# Showing data from database in AmCharts

Tags: mysql, json, charts, amcharts

I'm trying to make graph using AmCharts and following this example on their site: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-data-loader-to-connect-charts-to-mysql-data-base/

My original code is

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chart_1", {
        "pathToImages": App.getGlobalPluginsPath() + "amcharts/amcharts/images/",

        "dataProvider": [{
            "year": 2009,
            "income": 23.5,
            "expenses": 18.1
        }, {
            "year": 2010,
            "income": 26.2,
            "expenses": 22.8
        }],
            // bunch of graph stylings
    });

    $('#chart_1').closest('.portlet').find('.fullscreen').click(function() {
        chart.invalidateSize();
    });
}
```

My attempt to load data from mysql

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chart_1", {
    "type": "serial",
    "dataProvider": {
        "url": "data.php"
    },
        "pathToImages": App.getGlobalPluginsPath() + "amcharts/amcharts/images/",

      // bunch on graphs style

    });

    $('#chart_1').closest('.portlet').find('.fullscreen').click(function() {
        chart.invalidateSize();
    });
}
```

The original code with data which is hardcoded is working. The below with mysql doesn't work. It's blank page and doesn't show the graph. Also no errors on console.

`data.php` is working also and return json array.

Can anyone help here?

In case php part is needed also

```
$query = "
       SELECT *
       FROM my_chart_data
       ORDER BY category ASC";
$result = $link->query( $query );

// All good?
if ( !$result ) {
  // Nope
  $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . $link->error . "n";
  $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
  die( $message );
}


// Set proper HTTP response headers
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );

// Print out rows
$data = array();
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `dataProvider` doesn't take a url - you need to change it to `dataLoader` if you're using the dataLoader plugin. To use the dataLoader plugin, you first need to include the plugin along with the other chart libraries like so:

```
<!-- chart libraries -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<!-- include dataloader -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>
```

Then change `dataProvider` to `dataLoader`. `dataLoader` takes a `url`:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chart_1", {
    "type": "serial",
    "dataLoader": {
        "url": "data.php"
    },
    // ...
});
```

Full dataloader documentation can be found on the github page [here](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader/).

Comment: Thanks. I've got strange error in console `GET http://localhost/dashboard/text/javascript 404 (Not Found)` on this line `<script src="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Whoops. I typed `src` twice into my script tags. Change the `src="text/javascript"` to `type="text/javascript"`. My morning tea didn't kick in yet. Sorry.

Comment: thanks, your answer points me to right direction, learning more from the serial json examples from amcharts dataloader plugins folder, solve my problems

Comment: How to do this with socket? As I want to fetch data from database every minute and display it in amchart4. But my problem here is my page is hanging after that.

Comment: @Kirataka - you're posting an amcharts v4 question on a v3 answer made years ago. I suggest you post a separate question if you haven't already done so.

Comment: @xorspark https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61273451/page-becomes-unresponsive-when-data-added-to-amchart4-through-socket. This would help